# Where is the online help text located in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

A while ago, I extracted the actual Online Help Texts (in-game help strings accessible from the Help menu when the game runs) from Fallout 76 from the main `.ba2` file for better readability. I've used the [Bethesda Archive Extractor](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/78/) (free signup required for downloads). Doing this was relatively straightforward, with some amount of copy-paste. :-)

Now I wanted to the same for Fallout 4, but I fail to find the strings. I've extracted *Fallout4 - Interface.ba2*, as well as the DLC's strings. `grep`ing through these files for strings gleaned from the actual online help window within the game revealed no matches — just unlike Fallout 76 extracted strings.

Where can I find the online help text strings from Fallout 4? And how can I extract these to a file, if they are located in kind-of-an archive?

I'm asking this question in here because I fail to find a better place on Stackexchange. Proposals where to ask better are welcome.

Comment: With "Online Help Texts" you mean the in-game help strings?

Comment: Yes. I've updated the question to be more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can be found in the `Fallout4 - Interface.ba2` archive file, in the /Strings folder.
There you can find .STRINGS, .DLSTRINGS, and .ILSTRINGS files for all supported languages.

You can use [BSA Browser](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/17061) or an equivalent to extract them. BSA Browser for Skyrim, and likely other Bethesda games, works perfectly fine, in case you already have any other installed.

[image: screenshot of the BSA Browser with 'Fallout 4 - Interface.ba2' opened]

You can use [xTranslator](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/134?tab=files&file_id=267836) to read the .STRINGS files:

[image: screenshot of xTranslator with 'Fallout4_en.STRINGS' opened and the description for the Cap(s) Collector perk selected]

(And that randomly selected string already displays an inconsistency: the perk is called 'Cap Collector', but the description reads 'Caps Collector". Typical Bethesda.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know why my other grep over those extracted strings failed. Also thanks for the hint to xTranslator!